# Loop within a loop

Tags: python, for-loop

Confuse about the code below,as you see, there is a loop in another loop, and I checked the similar answers from stackoverflow but still don't get it...

```
grid = [
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

for x in range(len(grid)):#0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
    for y in range(len(grid[0])):#0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
        print(grid[x][y], end='')
    print('')
```

I expected the output like this:

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

But actually the result is :

```
......
.OO...
OOOO..
OOOOO.
.OOOOO
OOOOO.
OOOO..
.OO...
......
```

What is the regulation for the double loops?

Comment: `x` and `y` are swapped thus rotating the output from what you expect. What you got is a duplicate of the input as written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current loop first selects the first element in the list, which is a list of only dots, and then goes through that and prints. You need to change it so it selects the first element of each list, then each element in the second position in each list.

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

for x in range(len(grid[0])):#0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
    for y in range(len(grid)):#0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
        print(grid[y][x], end='')
    print('')
```

Like so. Swapped x and y in the `print` command, and changed it so the `for` ranges are correct. With double loops, it first picks the `x` value in the first loop, and then goes thought a loop with `y` values and that constant `x` value. Then it picks the next `x` value and a does a loop with all `y` values again.

Output:

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

Answer (score 2):

you just go over the index in each list in the big list.
If you want the output to be like you want you need to change

```
print(grid[x][y], end='')
```

to

```
print(grid[y][x], end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

It goes inside the outer loop, and then enters the inner loop. When it completes this inner loop, it goes back to the outer loop, where it again enters the inner loop. This repeats until it completes the outer loop.

So basically it completes the outer loop only once, but completes the inner loop the *number of iterations in outer loop* times.

Looking at your code, it will get grid[0][y] by looping through the inner loop with `y` being the inner loop variable, then does grid[1][y], then grid[2][y], and so on... It does this `x` times. `x` and `y` here are your grid dimensions.

Edit: to get it to show the way you want, just exchange `x` and `y`... Like so: grid[y][x]

Answer (score 0):

Just need to flip the two loops (y and x):

```
for x in range(len(grid)):#0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
    for y in range(len(grid[0])):#0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
        print(grid[y][x], end='')
    print('')
```

And if you notice, your heart *is* showing up, it's just rotated 90-degrees.

I like to use `r` and `c` variables for these types of loops where `r` stands for row and `c` stands for column. Makes it easier to understand the logic.